# Moving chat messages only takes into account messages selected before clicking "relocate"

Tags: bug, chat

How to reproduce:

- Select room -> move messages
- Select a message
- Click "relocate" and type in the name of the room
- Select one more message
- Select the room by clicking "choose"

[image: bug preview]

Comment: This gets me constantly. Really annoying when you see an extra message you want to move.

Comment: That's undefined behavior and should be avoided.

Comment: It's like they made a modal without making it, you know, modal.

Comment: [status-bydesign] kick first, move later ;)